# Append Two Files different total record

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have two files. file 1 contain 7 column with 100 record. file 2 contain 2 column with 1 record.
i want to put column 2 from file 2 in last column of file 1.

i try with paste -d and pr -mtr it just new column adding in first record.

Below is the expected process

**files1.txt**

```
aaaa|bbb|ccc|dddd|eee|fff|ggg
aawe|bab|fcc|dcvd|ere|fasdf|g12g
aaas|bcb|dcc|ddsd|efe|ff|g2
.....
aaa2|bb3|ccd|ddsd|eef|ffd|gag
```

**files2.txt**

```
abc|def
```

output

**files3.txt**

```
aaaa|bbb|ccc|dddd|eee|fff|ggg|def
aawe|bab|fcc|dcvd|ere|fasdf|g12g|def
aaas|bcb|dcc|ddsd|efe|ff|g2|def
.....
aaa2|bb3|ccd|ddsd|eef|ffd|gag|def
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{x=$2;next} $(NF+1)=x' file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: Welcome, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

`sed` seems like an obvious choice.

```
IFS='|' read x add < file2.txt
sed "s/$/|$add/" file1.txt > file3.txt
```